# Rails Ajax redirect, doesn`t change the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I have a `character_form` with `js: true`

This are my controller actions:

```
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @character = Character.new
    @clan = Clan.where(name: params[:clan]).take || Clan.where(name: "Feniks").take
    @families = @clan.families
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js      
      format.html     
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @character = @user.characters.new(character_params)

    if @character.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @clan = Clan.where(name: params[:character][:clan]).take 
      @families = @clan.families
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And `user#show` action:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @characters = @user.characters.all.order(:family, :name)
  end
```

After I submit the `character_form` the server shows:

```
Started POST "/users/1/characters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-17 01:55:20 -0400
Processing by CharactersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "character"=>{"name"=>"Q mlak", "clan"=>"Feniks", "family"=>"Agasha", "desc"=>"alalalal"}, "commit"=>"Zapisz", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (5.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.4ms)  INSERT INTO "characters" ("name", "clan", "desc", "family", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Q mlak"], ["clan", "Feniks"], ["desc", "alalalal"], ["family", "Agasha"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-11-17 05:55:20.778436"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-17 05:55:20.778436"]]
   (30.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 52ms (ActiveRecord: 40.7ms)


Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-17 01:55:20 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Character Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "characters"."family" ASC, "characters"."name" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (8.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_gretel.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 423ms (Views: 415.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

I don`t have create.js.erb nor show.js.erb files.

My problem is that the view in the browser doesn't fallow the server. I know that ajax fakes the screen. My goal is to redirect to `current_user` path as html after form is submitted.

Comment: You don't need to use the remote: true option and everything will work as intended.

Comment: ok thnx I will do it.